# Intent Uri data disappears when processing metadata for audio file

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, uri

I am making a metadata retriever function for my **Mediaplayer program** for android. I've been trying to get Uri for `setDataSource` function of `MediaMetadataRetriever(`). However The Uri I get from my filechooser activity when the media file is selected disappears and I am getting a null object reference when running my metadata retriever function. I tried running a while loop on audioFileUri file location to verify the media file Uri was stored in memory throughout the programs lifecycle. I am stumped as to why it is returning a null object reference.

So far I've tried:

1. Converting Uri to String.
2. Changing the metaretriever source to accept String data source.
3. Logging the output of the audioFileUri to make sure it's a value Uri address of the media file.
4. Playing a sound off the sdcard instead of google drive.
5. Using data.getDataString() to get the media file location as a String.

Here is the code:

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final int REQUEST_OPEN_FILE = 1;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    Uri audioFileUri;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    ImageView album_art;
    TextView album, artist, genre;
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);

        final Button playButton = findViewById(R.id.play);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                play();
            }
        });
        final Button pauseButton = findViewById(R.id.pause);
        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                pause();
            }
        });
        final Button stopButton = findViewById(R.id.stop);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stop();
            }
        });
        seekBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.open_file_action) {
            Intent audiofile_chooser_intent;
            audiofile_chooser_intent = new Intent();
            audiofile_chooser_intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            audiofile_chooser_intent.setType("audio/*");

            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(audiofile_chooser_intent,
                    getString(R.string.select_audio_file_title)), REQUEST_OPEN_FILE);

            Toast.makeText(this, "File Chooser initiated..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        } else if (id == R.id.second_item) {
            quit();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_OPEN_FILE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                audioFileUri = data.getData();

                GetMetaData getMetaData = new GetMetaData();
                getMetaData.metaRetriver();
            }
        }
        startMediaPlayer();
    }

    public void startMediaPlayer() {
        try {

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() || !mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, audioFileUri);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
                seekBar.setProgress(0);
                seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration()); // Set the Maximum range of the
                seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, audioFileUri);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
                seekBar.setProgress(0);
                seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration()); // Set the Maximum range of the
                seekBar.getVisibility();
                seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int mediaPos = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        int mediaMax = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        seekBar.setMax(mediaMax); // Set the Maximum range of the
        seekBar.setProgress(mediaPos);// set current progress to song's
        handler.removeCallbacks(moveSeekBarThread);
        handler.postDelayed(moveSeekBarThread, 300);


        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser) {
                    seekBar.setProgress(progress);
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void quit() {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
        android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void play() {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying() || mediaPlayer == null) {
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } else {
            Log.i("DEBUG_TAG", "No File loaded");
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null || mediaPlayer.isPlaying() || mediaPlayer == null) {
            seekBar.setProgress(0);
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
        }
    }

    /*public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }*/

    private Runnable moveSeekBarThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {

                int mediaPos_new = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                int mediaMax_new = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                seekBar.setMax(mediaMax_new);
                seekBar.setProgress(mediaPos_new);
                handler.postDelayed(this, 300); //Looping the thread after 0.1 second
                // seconds
            }

        }

    };
}
```

And here is my metadata retriever class:

```
public class GetMetaData extends MainActivity {
    ImageView album_art;
    TextView album, artist, genre;
    MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever;
    byte[] art;
    Uri audioMeta = audioFileUri;

    public void metaRetriver() {
        /*super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);*/
        getInit(); // Ablum_art retrieval code

        metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        if (audioMeta == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            metaRetriever.setDataSource(this, audioMeta);
        }

        try {
            art = metaRetriever.getEmbeddedPicture();
            Bitmap songImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(art, 0, art.length);
            album_art.setImageBitmap(songImage);
            album.setText(metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM));
            artist.setText(metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST));
            genre.setText(metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            album_art.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            album.setText("Unknown Album");
            artist.setText("Unknown Artist");
            genre.setText("Unknown Genre");
        }
    }

    public void getInit() {
        album_art = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.album_art);
        album = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Album);
        artist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artist_name);
        genre = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.genre);
    }
```

DEBUG:

```
2019-02-13 12:31:58.622 18514-18514/com.example.macyg.androidmediaplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.macyg.androidmediaplayer, PID: 18514
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/12 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.example.macyg.androidmediaplayer/com.example.macyg.androidmediaplayer.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:182)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:520)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
        at com.example.macyg.androidmediaplayer.GetMetaData.getInit(GetMetaData.java:46)
        at com.example.macyg.androidmediaplayer.GetMetaData.metaRetriver(GetMetaData.java:21)
        at com.example.macyg.androidmediaplayer.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:110)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4353)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: **UPDATE** so I tried moving the method from a separate class file to the main program, now it's working. Not sure why having it in a separate class file prevented it from working.